# List last X malloc/free calls in Xcode, iOS

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode

Debugging iOS in Xcode, with the following environment variables set:

```
MallocCheckHeapStart=1
MallocCheckHeapEach=10
MallocStackLogging=1
MallocStackLoggingNoCompact=1
```

The heap checker will report and break if it finds corruption, checking every 10 heap operations.

So how do I know what those last 10 heap operations were?

I know `malloc_info --stack-history` can give me the history for a particular pointer, but in this case I don't know about any pointers, I just know that heap corruption occurred in the last 10 operations.

Is there a way I can list the last X heap operations so I can find the heap corruption culprit?

Comment: @Olaf Xcode does more than just Objective-C, and in my particular case the vast majority of what I'm working on is in C and C++ running on iOS.  (There is an Objective-C layer on top of it, but the heap corruption I'm experiencing is causing crashes in the C and C++ code).

Comment: Ok then. Sorry, there's just too many noobs here selecting every tag starting with the proper letter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2009/01/checking-malloc-history/) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) article already? The gdb command `malloc_history` is referenced there...

I'm not sure if thats what you're looking for, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Yes, that's the stuff I already knew.  It seems like it should be possible to get a list of the last X allocations without filtering for a specific pointer when your stack logs are being written to disk, but I don't know how (or really if) it is possible.  Thus my question :)